# How can I clear the cached URLs for my Facebook App?

Tags: facebook

The settings page of a Facebook app gives you options to set the following:

Page Tab URL

Page Tab Secure URL

Canvas URL

Canvas Secure URL

In my case, all 4 have been changed, but when I go to the URL of the Facebook app, Facebook still tries to load the old URLs, which are HTTP, and hence do not load over HTTPs.

It has been more than 24 hours, but I need to have this cache cleared in order to have my app reviewed under the new deprecation rules.
I have already tried using the URL Debugger.

That does not seem to help.

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs . The change should go though in a few minutes

Comment: Done, let's see what the response is.

Comment: I answered on the bug too but: After debugging I'm pretty sure you are doing something wrong. My guess is that when we do a POST request to https://www.yourdomain.com you redirect to http://. . If you look at in the Developer Console when loading your canvas page you can see that Facebook tries to load the https version of your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
My domain currently redirects from https to http using a 301. While this is a fairly standard implementation of https right now, it is not supported by Facebook.

Comment: It is totally supported by Facebook. I mean Facebook don't care at all. It is every single browser that doesn't support it. That is why Chrome, Firefox, IE and every other browser gives you the error and not Facebook.